# Remapping Emacs' Meta to Windows keys on Kubuntu

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, kubuntu

After quite a few hours of searching now, I still can't work out how to do this.

Setup:

- French Windows Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 (which is why I want to remap)
- HP Pavilion dm4 laptop running Kubuntu 12.04.
- Emacs 24.3.1 cassou-emacs-precise

I simply want the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> keys (+ left <kbd>Alt</kbd> if it's easier) to map to the <kbd>◆ Meta</kbd> key in Emacs. I have tried everything I can think of - `xev` tells me that the keys are mapped to `META_L` and `META_R` from KDE's point of view - why on earth am I having so much trouble?

I've seen lots of stuff about remapping "mac-..." and "w32-..." stuff but I'm running neither a Mac, nor Windows. Why is <kbd>Alt</kbd> no good for my <kbd>◆ Meta</kbd>? <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> (right <kbd>Alt</kbd>) is used for lots of letters on a French keyboard and it's not practical to change that and I want a <kbd>◆ Meta</kbd> key on the right side of the keyboard.

So I have done further research: Using Konsole and `emacs -nw` does not work but if I change this either with KDE's keyboard management app or `xmodmap` then it *does* work with Emacs in GUI mode.
Win_R-w then C-h l gives:

M-w C-h l

for Emacs in GUI mode and

ESC [ > 0 ; 1 1 5 ; 0 c w C-h l

in emacs -nw in Konsole.

Comment: Could you please explain what you have tried, and how it fails. Your last paragraph seems to imply that you have solved it.

Comment: @terdon Only for Emacs frames on the X server, though. If it still doesn't work in Konsole, despite being `xmodmap`ped to what you want it to be, the implication is that Konsole is doing something with the keystroke before passing it to Emacs; I'd be interested to see the output of `M-x view-lossage` (`C-h l`) after a chord involving the problematic key.

Comment: @AaronMiller that's right. I get:

ESC [ > 0 ; 1 1 5 ; 0 c w C-h l

After trying Win_L and Win_R with the character 'w' and then C-h l.

Comment: @Antonovich Your comment ends with "I get:"; perhaps it'd work better to edit the lossage into your question? -- oh, there it is.

Comment: @AaronMiller - It's my first time posting so it's taking me a while to get the formatting right! Thanks for your patience...

Comment: @Antonovich No worries, and welcome to Super User! We're glad to have you with us. OK, so Konsole is translating the Meta keypress into an ANSI escape code (`ESC [` &c.) I see the same behavior in Konsole, and it seems plausible there'd be a way to convince Emacs it should recognize such sequences. I don't know yet how that might be done, but let me see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Antonovich Well, that didn't take long: apparently the problem is with Konsole mishandling the key, not with Emacs misunderstanding the input, and to solve it requires [patching the source and rebuilding](http://patchwork.trinitydesktop.org/patch/146/). Seems like it might just be easier to have Emacs talk to your X server...

Comment: @AaronMiller - or using gnome-terminal... Wow that's annoying! You've answered my question - how do I mark you comment as an answer? (and how do I delete this comment? :-))

Comment: @Antonovich Comments can't be marked as answers, but answers can, so I've just added one. If you mouse over a comment, it should reveal a 'circled X' after your name, which can be clicked to delete the comment. (Also, Gnome Terminal seems to have the same problem Konsole does, judging by the lossage...)

Comment: @AaronMiller Thanks and done. Gnome Terminal works fine for me so I think I'll go with that for the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to result from the way in which Konsole handles the Meta key, and requires [a source patch](http://patchwork.trinitydesktop.org/patch/146/) to fix. (In the following, 'a' is the unpatched version, and 'b' is the patched.)

```
--- a/konsole/konsole/TEmuVt102.cpp
+++ b/konsole/konsole/TEmuVt102.cpp
@@ -945,7 +945,8 @@  void TEmuVt102::onKeyPress( TQKeyEvent* ev )
                                      encodeMode(MODE_AppScreen     , BITS_AppScreen ) + // VT100 stuff
                                      encodeStat(TQt::ControlButton , BITS_Control   ) +
                                      encodeStat(TQt::ShiftButton   , BITS_Shift     ) +
-                                     encodeStat(TQt::AltButton     , BITS_Alt       ),
+                                     encodeStat(TQt::AltButton     , BITS_Alt       ) +
+                                     encodeStat(TQt::MetaButton        , BITS_Alt   ),
                           &cmd, &txt, &len, &metaspecified ))
 //printf("cmd: %d, %s, %d\n",cmd,txt,len);
   if (connected)
@@ -977,7 +978,7 @@  void TEmuVt102::onKeyPress( TQKeyEvent* ev )
     scr->setHistCursor(scr->getHistLines());

   if (cmd==CMD_send) {
-    if ((ev->state() & TQt::AltButton) && !metaspecified ) sendString("\033");
+    if (((ev->state() & TQt::AltButton) || (ev->state() & TQt::MetaButton)) && !metaspecified ) sendString("\033");
     emit sndBlock(txt,len);
     return;
   }
```